# Positioning the lower-alpha bullets bullets of a order list

Tags: html, css

Using the CSS below I can get a list using lower-alpha bullets with braces on each side, but now the counter appears as if in the content with no separation, so it looks like:

What occurs:

```
(a) this is my content in the list item
that has the bullets inlined with the 
content
```

What I'd like:

```
(a) this is what I'd rather have that
    occurs in native lists, but doesn't
    have lower-alpha with braces
```

The CSS:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: list;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px;
}

ol > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content: "(" counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
/*    position: absolute;
    left: -1.4em;*/
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had it. If there is padding on the left that serves as displacement, you can absolutely position the pseudo element *relative* to the parent:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: list;
    padding: 0;
}
ol > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content:"(" counter(list, lower-alpha)") ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut maximus elit nec tortor facilisis varius. Quisque id elit sollicitudin nunc bibendum aliquet id in massa. Nam mattis est at hendrerit pretium. Vivamus tempus interdum dolor, eu dictum enim auctor sit amet. Mauris quis finibus dolor</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut maximus elit nec tortor facilisis varius. Quisque id elit sollicitudin nunc bibendum aliquet id in massa. Nam mattis est at hendrerit pretium. Vivamus tempus interdum dolor, eu dictum enim auctor sit amet. Mauris quis finibus dolor</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut maximus elit nec tortor facilisis varius. Quisque id elit sollicitudin nunc bibendum aliquet id in massa. Nam mattis est at hendrerit pretium. Vivamus tempus interdum dolor, eu dictum enim auctor sit amet. Mauris quis finibus dolor</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right it does look like I had it, but I guess I didn't make the displacement enough and it looked like it did nothing.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you just uncomment the **absolute position** property it works.

```css
ol > li:before {
  counter-increment: list;
  content: "(" counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.4em;
}
```

Here you can see a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/416qfvfn/